# Не могу получить рабочую ссылку на скачивание на Laravel

Tags: laravel

Приложение на Laravel 5.3 благополучно закачивает файлы посетителя в папку /public/upload/? но при попытке прописать в ссылке, например    `<a href="/public/upload/1.jpg">`
 Скачать  пишет Internal server error? но файл там точно есть, и рисунки по тегу img src он выводит на экран
Что не правильно? Мне надо, чтобы была возможность скачивания загруженных файлов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте **URL::to**

```
<a href="{{URL::to('public/upload/1.jpg')}}>
```

Comment: вообще, проблема была в другом, библиотека обработки ошибок вызывал сбой